# How to embed a mp4 file in the body field?

Tags: entities, media, files

Just that. I need to embed a mp4 file in the body field of a node. I'm pretty sure I can do this with the **media**, **ckeditor** and **wysiwyg** modules. But I just need to embed one video in the entire site, then enabling and doing all the setting just for one video seems a waste of time to me.

Is there any way to it in a simpler way?

Comment: An embedded mp4 is just an `<object>` or `<video>` at the heart of it - if you want to avoid installing a bunch of modules, [preparing the markup yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299347/how-do-i-embed-a-mp4-movie-into-my-html) would be the easiest solution